# How does weapon power work in FTL

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I cannot seem to work out how the power works for weapons in FTL.

I picked up a Hull Laser II that consumes 3 power. I already had the Burst Laser II (consumes 1 power). 
I upgraded my power and got another bar, then upgraded my weapon system  so I have 4 bars available in my weapon systems.

So I *should* be able to power up my Burst Laser power 1 and Hull Laser power 3 = 4 but it keeps saying I don't have enough power.

I can turn off everything and have plenty of actual power available but i still can't power up the hull laser. I don't get it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have other weapons activated?  Missiles and bombs take power as well.  Otherwise, I don't see a problem with what you're describing.  Can you take a screenshot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Burst Laser II uses 2 power. Upgrade weapons system capacity one more and buy an additional bar of power.

Comment: OMG Even though I checked several times I could have sworn the Burst Laser II used 1 power. Looking at it again it does indeed need 2 so I just need 1 more power slot in weapons to ruin both together. Duh! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have the weapons *capacity* and then you have overall power *budget*. So you need enough weapons-power slots, and *then* you need to fill those slots with power from your reactor.

If you are routing all your reactor power to other systems, you will not be able to supply power to the weapon(s). To remove power from a system, right click it.

If you decide to take all power from the 02 system, don't forget that you have done so or your crew will suffocate